# How to create dynamic cell in tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am facing issue regarding Dynamic cell in UITableView. I want to create dynamic rows while user clicked on button in tableview.

E.g.: in mytableview there are two rows as following :

1. Car        :+
2. Bike       :+

When user clicked add button then I have to show two more rows below car cell same thing as while user clicked on in front of bike add button then I have to show two more cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have 2 sections, a bike and a car section with two data arrays to manage content of all cells. You may need to have two types of cell, an "add" cell and a "standard" cell.

Here is an example:

-In your viewDidiLoad:

```
self.bikeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"Add bike"]]; // Aray to fill section 0
self.carArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"Add car"]]; // Aray to fill section 1
self.typeOfVehicleArray = @[@"Bike", @"Car"];
self.dataArray = @[self.bikeArray, self.carArray];
```

To create two types of cell, check indexPath.row:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:{
            NSString *addIdentifier = @"addIdentifier";
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:addIdentifier];
            if (!cell){
                // Add button...
                CGFloat buttonWidth = 60.f;
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:addIdentifier];
                UIButton *b = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - buttonWidth - 10.f , 5.f, buttonWidth, cell.frame.size.height - 10.f)];
                [b setTitle:@"ADD" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                // ...with a wonderful color
                b.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                [b addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [cell addSubview:b];
                [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
            }

            break;
        }
        default:{
           NSString *standardIdentifier = @"standardIdentifier";
           cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:standardIdentifier];
            if (!cell){
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:standardIdentifier];
                [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    NSArray *vehicleArray = self.dataArray[indexPath.section];
    cell.textLabel.text = [vehicleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Don't forget number of cells / sections:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.dataArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *vehicleArray = self.dataArray[section];
    return [vehicleArray count];
}
```

Then you can implement buttonPressed:

```
- (void) buttonPressed: (id)sender{
    // Find the section
    UIButton *b = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[b superview];
    NSInteger section = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell].section;

    // Get vehicle array (bikeArray or carArray)
    NSMutableArray *vehicleArray = self.dataArray[section];
    NSString *vehicleType = [self.typeOfVehicleArray objectAtIndex:section];
    NSInteger nextVehicle = [vehicleArray count];
    NSString *firstRowToAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %lu", vehicleType, (long)nextVehicle];
    NSString *secondRowToAdd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %lu", vehicleType, (long)(nextVehicle + 1)];

    // Add object in vehicle array
    [vehicleArray addObject:firstRowToAdd];
    [vehicleArray addObject:secondRowToAdd];

    // Create array of corresponding indexPath and update tableview
    NSArray *indexPathArray = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:nextVehicle inSection:section],
                            [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(nextVehicle + 1) inSection:section]];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: I added missing number of cells/sections and you have everything :)

Comment: thank you very much for shared your code. i need your help regarding i want to show only data like bike : Bajaj , Honda, Suzuki model while user click add button and save .

Comment: i have to show dynamic data while user click add button.:(

Comment: Sorry Mukund Raj, but I think you need to update your post and add information like: how do you get this data, what does it look like....

Answer (score 0):

You can control number rows in [UITableView's tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:) function that is defined in UITableViewDataSource Protocol. Just define an integer variable that holds the number rows user should see. On every Add button click increase the value of variable.

```
@implementation ViewController {
     int numberOfRows;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    numberOfRows = 3;
}

-(IBAction) addButtonClicked
{
    numberOfRows++;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return numberOfRows;
}
```

Comment: I have to show three rows after click add button , now i am doing this way is creating rows but my previous rows has deleted & showing new rows, but I need like expand view. it should be show my previous constant and when click add button then it should be increse my rows one by one and Bike rows will be constant to show when i will do my previous activities.

Comment: In this case you can _connect numberOfRows_ value to a function, that calculates how many rows should be there.

-(int)numberOfRows {
int numberOfBikeRows = 3;
int numberAddedWithButton = 2;
.. do your own implementation
}